# Purging Data of a large postgres table

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-rds

We used to store logs in a postgres table and with time that table has grown in size more than 600GB. We tried to implement the purging strategy on the table to delete table's data. Purging query run fine and returns with number of rows deleted, however the table size is still not reducing.

We tried to delete the data using delete queries and more than 348 million rows were deleted. The size still didn't reduce. Auto-vacuum process was also monitored which ran fine but size still didn't reduce.

We are using RDS postgres and the current storage capacity of RDS is around 1200GB, free space is around 100GB. I want to know if I am missing anything.

Comment: I think https://dba.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask this question, vote to close.

Comment: DELETE doesn't return disk space, nor does (auto) VACUUM. auto vacuum can only create space for future inserts. If you need the disk space, you have to recreate the table, vacuum full or reorganize the table. Table partitioning could be of help as well, just drop an entire partition an there is no need anymore for auto vacuum or any other proces to reorganize the data.

Comment: I truncated the table to actually regain the table space and it work. Thanks!